# Store JSON text output in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to store a "text" using **NSString** from my JSON output but it's not working because it's always NULL. It's working fine with the other info (because they are integers) but when I have to store the info (the picture) in a NSString it's always NULL.

I have tried to search a lot of places in order to see how I have to declare that "NSString" and make it work but it's not working and I need some help.

Can you help me with that? How can I fill the **NSString** with the information in "picture" from my **JSON** output?

**ProfileViewController**:

```
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
        NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];

NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];

    NSString *picture = [jsonData objectForKey:@"picture"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picture]];
    self.profileimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

**JSON output**:

```
{"success":1,"stars":0,"photos":0,"followers":0,"picture":http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/p/3/000/25b/1fe/200e9f3.jpg}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `NSLog([jsonData class])` and tell me what's the output. I'm not sure if it's NSDictionary.

Comment: You need to provide more info. In the code you posted, is `jsonData` coming back as `nil` or not? If not, is `picture` `nil` or not?

Comment: Why is the picture URL in your JSON output not in quotes?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Xcode. Please stop adding the Xcode tags.

Comment: Here is a major mistake: `error:nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct, however the JSON output is not valid according to http://jsonlint.com/

You need to wrap the link with quotes ("http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/p/3/000/25b/1fe/200e9f3.jpg") and then try again.